# How to compare each group of one table with a column in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

**TypeTable**

```
TypeId      PersonClassificationId
----------------------

 1           1  
 1           2 
 1           3 
 2           1 
 2           2
```

**PersonClassificationTable**

```
PersonClassificationId Capacity
----------------------

 1                        2  
 2                        2 
 3                        2
```

I need to select such **TypeId** that in the entire TypeTable table **do not have at least one PersonClassificationID specified in PersonTable**.

So, if PersonTable has 1, 2, 3, then TypeId = 2 should be selected, because **there is no record in TypeTable**:

```
TypeId      PersonClassificationId
----------------------

 2           3
```

How can I do that?
It is undesirable to use cursors : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can do what you want by generating all possible combinations of types and classifications, and then filter on those that do not exist in the mapping table:

```
select t.TypeId, pc.PersonClassificationId
from (select distinct TypeId from TypeTable) t
cross join PersonClassificationTable p
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from TypeTable t1 
    where t1.TypeId = t.TypeId and t1.PersonClassificationId = p.PersonClassificationId
)
```